# How can I record a sound and play it back after a user-defined delay in Python?

Tags: python, audio, wav, wave, pyaudio

I'm looking for a Python's code that would record a sound and play it back after a certain delay (for example 10 seconds). In other words, I would like to constantly hear (on my headphones) what's going on outside, but with a certain delay.

I found a Python script on GitHub (https://gist.github.com/larsyencken/5641402) that is supposed to do what I'm looking for. However, when I run the script, the playing starts after 5 seconds (default delay), but it records everything around and plays it in real time (without any delay).

Comment: Asking for recommendations is off-topic on Stack Overflow. You can ask on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ but be sure to [provide enough information](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)

Comment: Thanks @greg-449. I just edited my question here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using `sounddevice` , although you can do it using other `audio/sound` modules as well.

Below example records audio from microphone for `#seconds` as per variable `duration` which you can modify as per your requirements.
Same contents are played back using standard audio output (speakers).
More on this [here](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.4/)

**Working Code**

```
import sounddevice as sd
import numpy as np
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav

fs=44100
duration = 10  # seconds
myrecording = sd.rec(duration * fs, samplerate=fs, channels=2, dtype='float64')
print "Recording Audio for %s seconds" %(duration)
sd.wait()
print "Audio recording complete , Playing recorded Audio"
sd.play(myrecording, fs)
sd.wait()
print "Play Audio Complete"
```

**Output**

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Recording Audio for 10 seconds
Audio recording complete , Playing recorded Audio
Play Audio Complete
>>>
```